# A function is quasilinear if its domain and all level sets are convex

Tags: convex-analysis

From section 3.4.1 of Stephen Boyd & Lieven Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook):

> A function is quasilinear if its domain and every level set $\{x \mid  f(x) = \alpha \}$ is convex.

How to prove it?

Comment: How to prove *what* exactly?

Comment: From the definition, a function is quasilinear if it's both quasiconvex and quasiconcave. I don't understand why the condition "the domain and every level set is convex" can lead to "being both quasiconvex and quasiconcave"